# perimeter of a regular pentagon inscribed in a circle of a given radius

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Ive seen how to solve this using law of cosines, but Im suposed to solve it using only angled triangle, I appreaciate a hint

Comment: What on earth is a "rectangle triangle"?

Comment: english is not my language i mean a triangle with an angle of 90 degrees

Comment: Ah, you mean a right triangle?

Comment: yes, I searched and thats the english word

Comment: All you have to know is the value of $\sin\frac\pi5$.

Comment: maybe think about the diameter ( flat side to vertex) of the pentagon and how that relates to the perimeter ? or even how many right triangles you can fit into the pentagon to split it up evenly)

Comment: Drop a perpendicular from the center of a circle to the side of a pentagon inscribed in that circle.  This perpendicular makes a 36-54-90 right triangle with the radius and half-side of the pentagon.  For a unit circle, the half-side of the pentagon =  $sin 36$.  Multiply this by  $10$ to get the perimeter of the pentagon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this image suffice as a hint?

[image: Pentagon split into ten right triangles]

The pentagon is split to five triangles by drawing a line from the center to each vertex.  Each of those triangles is subdivided into two right angled triangles by halving the angle.

Ten of the [right-angled triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle) (one shaded) form the pentagon.  You know the angle at the center vertex, and the length of the hypotenuse, so you can find out the length of the shorter leg (or shorter *cathetus*). With that, you can trivially find out the perimeter of the pentagon.

Comment: Yes, is the  angle at the center vertex 54 degrees? since eache angle is 108 degrees and that one is the half of one of those.

Did you make the image with any particular software?

Comment: @Sonny: Full turn is 360°, right? Since all ten right-angled triangles are the same, and share the center vertex, the angle at the center vertex should be one tenth of a full circle, right?

Comment: yes, or $2\pi / 10 = \pi / 5$. Thank you

Comment: Using that angle and radius 1, the answer is (one side of the pentagon)  $ 2 \sin{\pi /5}$. My first answer was thinking on the other angle, eache intern angle of the pentagon is 108 degrees, that one is half of it, so is 54 degrees since the side is the adjacent to that i use $2 \cos{54}$, gives the same answer

Comment: @Sonny: Quite true. The other non-right angle in the right angle triangles is indeed 54° (and two of them make up each internal angle in the pentagon). The sum of the angles in a triangle (on a flat plane) is 180°, and 90° + 36° + 54° = 180°. Also, $\cos(\theta) = \sin(90° - \theta)$, so $\sin 36° = \cos 54°$; thus your findings do make sense; you simply looked at the other vertex, not the ones at the center of the circle/pentagon. Finally, it is very good that you are trying to find the answers for yourself, and to understand the answers: it shows true interest, worth helping.